# testNG problem runing a suite with open browser

Tags: java, selenium, automated-tests, testng

I have 2 similar classes.
I changed the opening of the browser to ChromeOptions so the tests can't be execute when a browser is open.
When I am execute the testNG.xml (with the 2 tests) its open immiditly both of the browsers and the suite can't be run.
What should I need to change in order to execute this well ?
Thanks alot

```
public class Demo2 {

public static WebDriver driver;

public static void main(String[] args) 
{

    initializeDriver();
    print2();
}

@BeforeTest
private static void initializeDriver() {

    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Program Files\\Selenium\\chromedriver.exe");
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.addArguments("user-data-dir=C:/Users/עמית/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data");
    options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
    driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
    
}


@Test
public static void print2()
{
    driver.get("https://www.google.com");
    System.out.println("1");
    driver.close();
}
```

}

Comment: Can you share your testng.xml too

Answer (score 0):

I think this path C:/Users/עמית/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data") should use alphabet letters. Even if you try to use this, please config your font type to use the popular font as UTF-8.

Comment: Its works fine when I run it as a single class - the problem is only when I am trying to execute the testng.xml suite with 2 classes

Comment: please add more attachments.

Comment: Can you share your testng.xml and runner class please